# Can't read migration file using golang-migrate

Tags: golang-migrate

After running the `up` command, my database doesn't seem to be recognizing the SQL contained inside `relative/path/000001_init_schema.up.sql`.

So far:

- Verified I have a connection to the database
- Successfully executed the SQL inside my database manager (TablePlus)
- Relative path is correct (`-path db/migration`)

Full command:

```
migrate -path relative/path -database "postgresql://root:secret@localhost:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable" -verbose up
```

After running the command, I receive confirmation that "no changes have been made", but my database only has a `schema_migrations` table.

Any other ideas?

Thanks,
Connor

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by replacing `-path relative/path` with `-source file://relative/path`

Alternatively, you can use `-source file:///absolute/path`